# How should I write a feasibility study report?

Tags: best-practice, practical

I may be called upon to write a feasibility study report for consumer hardware (to be manufactured) and/or a service to be offered to clients in the near term. What is the proper technique here? Google says I need to start by suggesting alternate solutions and talking about how my solution is the best one; however my instructors say that I should just stick to my solution. Anybody have an outline maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a breakdown of the task in separate sub-problems and explain for each of them how you solve them. Make cost calculations. Comparing with alternate solutions you've studied is a good way to take away the wind from the client's sails: if *you* don't come up with alternatives (which you dismiss with good arguments) *he* might, and may come up with a better solution than yours.

Answer (score 0):

Tackle the situation in a organized manner.

For example, your not going to say "my idea is: your information here."

You want to come clear as possible with your claim as possible, but acknowledge the fact that there is other solutions, but yours is more outstanding because ( insert evidence here ).